# Find length of True sections in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, subset

I have a pandas series of True/False values.  I need to find the number of points for each time the series switches to True.

eg:

000011100000001100000001111100010000

would give me a results of [3,2,5,1]

I don't know where to start with this.  I'm hoping pandas has some clean way of doing it.

Comment: I am sure there could be other ways but this can be solved by simple loop. Just iterate over the list, keep a counter and count all the ones and reset counter once you hit a zero.

Comment: Your question is not very clear: you want to find the index where it switches to True, or you want to find the number of consecutive "True"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Setup**

```
string = '000011100000001100000001111100010000'
s = pd.Series(list(string)).astype(int)
```

**Solution**
Using `groupby` + `sum` and the `cumsum` trick

```
v = s.groupby(s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()).sum()    
v[v > 0].tolist()
[3, 2, 5, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one solution using `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

mystr = '000011100000001100000001111100010000'

s = pd.Series(list(map(int, mystr)))

res = [len(list(j)) for i, j in groupby(s) if i]

print(res)

# [3, 2, 5, 1]
```